# Windows Phone create DirectX App and C# library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, c++-cli, directx

My Visual Studio 2013 had just updated to Update 2 which the DirectX application changed from "C# with Interprop C++ dll" to "All are C++".

[image: DirectX App now doesn't use any C#!]

Now I want create a DirectX application but I have to use some classes in a dll library which written in C#. How can I do that?

Comment: There are several options: 1. Re-write the sample code to use C++/CLI. Then you can just reference the C# dll. However, this might be quite some work. 2. Make the relevant parts of your C# library COM visible and use COM interop to access them from C++. 3. Wrap the render code in a C++ dll and create a new main C# application that references the C# dll and uses the C++ dll (again per interop) to render stuff. It all depends on the circumstances.

Comment: File + Add + New Project, open C# + Store Apps and select Windows Phone Apps.  Pick the "Windows Runtime Component" template.